# Powershell command built dynamically -- Parameter Passing Issue

Tags: powershell

I am unable to understand Parameter passing behavior in Powershell.

Say, I have a script `callScript.ps1`

```
param($a="DefaultA",$b="DefaultB")
echo $a, $b
```

Say, another script calls `callScript.ps1`.

```
.\callScript.ps1
# outputs DefaultA followed by DefaultB as expected
.\callScript.ps1 -a 2 -b 3
# outputs 2 followed by 3 as expected
$arguments='-a 2 -b 3'
callScript.ps1 $arguments
# I expected output as previous statement but it is as follows.
# -a 2 -b 3
# DefaultB
```

How can I run a powershell script by constructing command dynamically as above?
Can you please explain why the script the `$arguments` is interpreted as `$a` variable in `callScript.ps1`?

Comment: You are passing a single string to you script which is expecting 2 parameters. Therefore it's fallbacking to DefaultB (which is missing). I think you should consider refactoring your function to accept an array instead. At least if you really need to pass parameters as a single argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's happening here is that you're passing a string:

`'-a 2 -b 3'` as the parameter for `$a`

you need to specify the values within the param, if you really needed to do it as you have above (there's definitely a better way though) you could do this using `Invoke-Expression` (short `iex`)

```
function doprint {
    param( $a,$b )
    $a ; $b
}

$arg = '-a "yes" -b "no"'

"doprint $arg" | iex
```

you could also change your function to take in an array of values like this:

```
function doprint {
    param( [string[]]$a )
    $a[0] ; $a[1]
}

$arg = @('yes','no')

doprint $arg
```

Answer (score 1):

As has already been hinted at, you can't pass a single string as your script is expecting two params - the string is taken as input for param `$a`, whilst param `$b` takes the default value.

You can however build a simple hash table containing your arguments, and then use [splatting](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/10/18/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts/) to pass them to the script.

The changes to your code are minimal:

```
$arguments=@{a="2";b="3"}

callScript.ps1 @arguments
```